# SQL 3 Table Join with IS NOT NULL

Tags: php, sql, join

I have 3 tables `com_co`, `sim`, `clist`

```
$list = "SELECT com_co.*, sim.*, clist.*
         FROM  com_co
            INNER   JOIN sim
              ON sim.id = com_co.component_id
            INNER   JOIN clist
              ON com_co.complex_id = clist.id AND IS NOT NULL
         WHERE comp_c_code = '$rowId'";
```

The query runs if I remove the second `INNER JOIN` but then I can't get data from `clist`. The column `complex_id` in table `com_co` can be `null`. If it is `not null` and has a value (an `id` from `clist`) I want to be able to get data from `clist` with that `ID`.

If I run this query I get no returned data.

Comment: `com_co.complex_id = clist.id AND IS NOT NULL` is not a valid SQL expression.

Comment: i think this will work SELECT com_co.*, sim.*, clist.*
         FROM  com_co
            INNER   JOIN sim
              ON sim.id = com_co.component_id
            INNER   JOIN clist
              ON com_co.complex_id = clist.id AND com_co.complex_id IS NOT NULL
         WHERE comp_c_code = '$rowId'

Comment: @astroanu it doesn't unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$list = "SELECT com_co.*, sim.*, clist.*
     FROM  com_co
        INNER   JOIN sim
          ON sim.id = com_co.component_id
        INNER   JOIN clist
          ON com_co.complex_id = clist.id 
     WHERE comp_c_code = '$rowId' AND com_co.complex_id  IS NOT NULL";
```